# 127.0.0.1 Error 404 but http://localhost works

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I've got a problem this my MAMP Pro, I don't understand...
127.0.0.1 give me a 404 error but http://localhost works.
I found no problem with my hosts configuration...

Maybe a problem with Apache but I don't know.

I'm on MAC OS High Sierra, My MAMP Pro version 4.4.1.

Comment: Did you try `http://128.0.0.1`?

Comment: @LaGriffeDigitale did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In MAMP Pro try editing host Setting: localhost

Add to Additional parameters for `<VirtualHost>`

```
ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are editing your host Localhost, in IP Address, choose your local ip (192.168.0.xxx).
And now, 127.0.0.1 is callable as your local ip 192.168.0.xxx